# Java not printing messages after `finally` block

Tags: java

This question relates to the `finally` blocks in Java. Here "rest of the code" is not printing, which is after the `finally` block.

But when an exception is not there then it will print whatever is after the `finally` block.

```
class TestFinallyBlock1 {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        try {  
            int data=25/0;  
            System.out.println(data);  
        }  
        catch(NullPointerException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
        }  
        finally {
           System.out.println("finally block is always executed");
        }  

        System.out.println("rest of the code...");  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you was not catching java.lang.ArithmeticException and code gets terminated at that point.

Try this:

```
class TestFinallyBlock1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            int data = 25 / 0;
            System.out.println(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally block is always executed");
        }
        System.out.println("rest of the code...");
    }
}
```

Comment: oh..yes.right.so this can be handle by ArithmeticException also.thank you.

Comment: You can catch multiple exception, and you should do it from the more specific to the less specific one